# call a zend view helper from a Class ( Not Controller )

Tags: zend-framework, view-helpers

how can i render phtml file inside ( a class inside library 'Not Controller' )  in Zend Frmework

and how i can pass parameter to it
I have this error:

Call to a member function render()

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
$view = new Zend_View();
$view->setScriptPath('../application/views/scripts');
$view->param1 = 'TEST';
$view->render('xyz.phtml');
```